# Toolbar Logo Size too small on Galaxy S7

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to set an app logo to the toolbar and its looks fine on most devices except the Samsung Galaxy S7. It looks **tiny** in this device !!

This is how I set the drawable to the toolbar in my Activity

```
//....
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setToolbarIcon();
//...

private void setToolbarIcon() {
    Drawable logo = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_logo);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setLogo(logo);
        toolbar.setTitle(null);
    }}
```

The below images will show you how the app logo sized related to the toolbar default title on 2 devices, Google Nexus 5X and Samsung Galaxy S7

**Nexus 5X**
[image: Toolbar of Nexus 5X]

**Galaxy S7**
[image: Toolbar of Galaxy S7]

This two green lines are showing how much difference in Title and logo rooms in the toolbar in each device.

Comment: save high resolution logo in xxhdpi or xxxhdpi

Answer (score 2):

It's because Galaxy S7 uses larger density and your logo is scaled with dp. Try adding xxxhdpi logo for devices with big densities

Check [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information

Comment: The current `app_logo.png` is `1200*370 px` which is highest resolution I can get.

Comment: Copy this image and inside android studio right click on drawable folder and paste it inside xxxhdpi folder

Answer (score 1):

While creating a different `Drawable` for each screen density works, you can also use a single `VectorDrawable` instead. Then you don't need to worry about different screen densities as the `VectorDrawable` gets scaled automatically. Creating a `VectorDrawable` out of your image can be a bit tricky though. These might help:

https://www.vectorizer.io/

http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a pro and free tools like vectorizer.io but I failed, this why I'm not using a vector in the first place. 

I'll give it a try, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The device Nexus 5x comes in the category of xxhdpi, where as s7 is in xxxhdpi. So you're not updating the drawable folders as required.